# Python: Plug result of function back into itself until it reaches 1, or if it loops forever break and print(sad)

Tags: python

I just started learning Python a few days ago, so forgive my crude work.

```
def sum_digits(n):
    s = 0
    while n:
        s += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return s

def IsHappy(x):
    sum_digits(x**2)==1
    while True:
        print("happy number")
        break
    while False:
```

Basically, i want a function that tests if a number is a happy number
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number
I figured out how to make it say "happy number" if the value is 1 on the first try.
However, if the value is not 1 on the first try, i want it to square the number, then sum the digits. I want it to repeat that until it gets 1. If it loops forever, i want it to print ("unhappy number").

Thanks.

Comment: use `if sum_digits(x**2) == 1:` instead of `while True`

Comment: how are you going to recognize that the loop will last forever and not 10 years or 10 minutes ?

Comment: Sounds as if you are describing the halting problem

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is you don't know the meaning of happiness -- you're summing the digits of the square instead of summing the squares of the digits.  The second issue is your unhappiness is unbounded -- your infinite loop will never achieve an unhappy, or any, result unless you have some sort of loop/cycle detection on your numbers.  A Python set is perfect for this purpose:

```
def sum_digits_squared(number):
    sum_squares = 0

    while number:
        sum_squares += (number % 10) ** 2
        number //= 10

    return sum_squares

def is_happy_number(number):
    seen_set = set()  # loop detection

    while True:
        sum_squares = sum_digits_squared(number)

        if sum_squares == 1:  # we reached 1 (happy)
            return True
        if sum_squares in seen_set:  # we have a loop (unhappy)
            return False

        seen_set.add(sum_squares)

        number = sum_squares

happiness = { True: "happy :-)", False: "not happy :-(" }

for n in range(1, 101):
    print(n, "is", happiness[is_happy_number(n)])
```

The third issue is that you're code doesn't work together logically.  But that will come with time, along with True happiness.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version based on cdlane's excellent answer, with a couple of enhancements.

The key idea is that if a sequence of numbers generated by `is_happy_number` ends in 1 then all of the numbers in that sequence are happy. Conversely, if `is_happy_number` finds a loop, not only is the original number unhappy, *all* of the numbers in that sequence are unhappy. So by collecting these sequences into happy and unhappy sets we can avoid a lot of re-calculation.

The code below runs in roughly 30% of the time of cdlane's version.

```
def sum_digits_squared(number):
    sum_squares = 0
    while number:
        number, digit = divmod(number, 10)
        sum_squares += digit ** 2
    return sum_squares

unhappy_set = set()
happy_set = set([1])

def is_happy_number(number):
    seen_set = set([number])  # loop detection
    while True:
        number = sum_digits_squared(number)
        if number in happy_set:
            happy_set.update(seen_set)
            return True
        if number in seen_set or number in unhappy_set:
            unhappy_set.update(seen_set)
            return False
        seen_set.add(number)

for n in range(1, 101):
    if is_happy_number(n):
        print(n, end=', ')
print()
```

**output**

```
1, 7, 10, 13, 19, 23, 28, 31, 32, 44, 49, 68, 70, 79, 82, 86, 91, 94, 97, 100,
```

---

We can improve the speed further with another trick. Python is quite fast at converting a numbers to strings and strings to numbers because those operations can be done at C speed. This allows us to extract digits quicker than using arithmetic that runs at Python speed.

Here's a version of `sum_digits_squared` that uses this trick:

```
def sum_digits_squared(number):
    return sum(int(d) ** 2 for d in str(number))
```

We can speed this up even more, by using a `dict` to eliminate converting the digit string back to an integer and squaring it.

```
digit_squares = dict((str(i), i*i) for i in range(10))
def sum_digits_squared(number):
    return sum(digit_squares[d] for d in str(number))
```

And we can gain a little more speed by doing this operation inline rather than making a function call.

```
unhappy_set = set()
happy_set = set([1])
digit_squares = dict((str(i), i*i) for i in range(10))

def is_happy_number(number):
    seen_set = set([number])  # loop detection
    while True:
        number = sum(digit_squares[d] for d in str(number))
        if number in happy_set:
            happy_set.update(seen_set)
            return True
        if number in seen_set or number in unhappy_set:
            unhappy_set.update(seen_set)
            return False
        seen_set.add(number)

for n in range(1, 101):
    if is_happy_number(n):
        print(n, end=', ')
print()
```

Comment: Yes, this problem is a nice one for introducing the memoization technique.

Comment: @cdlane: Indeed! I decided to use two sets rather than a single dict (as is more typical for memoization), since I figured it was both simpler to read and (probably) more efficient than updating a dict with the `seen_set` via `.fromkeys`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you must take advantage of the fact that unhappy numbers result in repeating sequences of numbers. Therefore, if your function generates a number that it has seen before, it must stop and output that the original input was an unhappy number, rather than looping indefinitely.

Working code:

```
def sum_digits(n):
    s = 0
    while n:
        s += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return s

def IsHappy(x):
    prev = []
    n = sum_digits(x)
    while n not in prev:
        if n == 1:
            print("Happy Number")
            return True
        else:
            prev.append(n)
            n = sum_digits(n)
    print("Unhappy Number")
    return False
```